# I have a dataset on a s3 server consisting of 1000s of images. How can I go about creating a database for the image metadata

Tags: python, database, image, opencv, amazon-s3

Some background information here.

I have a python module that will scrape certain websites and gather a few thousand images and upload it to an s3 server bucket (sorted by folders of the website name). Now I'm writing another OpenCV web application that will sift through this giant set of images and return ~5 image results.

There are 3 key pieces of information for each image: the image itself, the url of the website through which the image was extracted and the path of the image on the s3 server. Now how do I manage linking these three things together for each image ?

This entire thing worked when I ran it on the local filesystem since I created a text file which stored the local location and url of each image and when I was done sifting through the image set, I could simply query the text file and output the image url and image location. But now the image set is much much bigger and I need fast access to the metadata for each image.

I've had next to no experience with databases and web applications running on those databases for that matter so I'm confused as to how to get this huge data configured and up and running through a server.

Comment: Are there 8 things altogether? You mentioned 5 initially then 3...

Comment: Oh those are 5 images that will be returned from the OpenCV module once its done looping through the dataset. The 3 pieces of information associated with each image remain separate.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do or what the problem is. Put the 5 images in a directory - they will be fine there. Sore the 100s of other files in a different directory. Make an `sqlite` database that has several thousand rows - one row for each image. In each row, store the URL where the image came from and the path of the image on the S3 server. Don't store the actual image in the database - that will make it too big and unwieldy and hard to back-up.